# Nonce in proof of work

Tags: mining, proof-of-work

When a block is being mined nonce will be generated so that the nonce is appended with the previous block hash,data. Then the resulting hash of that appended value should be less than the target.

The question is Until the correct nonce is generated , will the nonce be appended to the previous block hash,data OR  for each try the nonce gets appended to the total hash produced by the previously produced nonce ?

Answer (score 2):

It works this way: a challenge number is generated starting from some stable but very new data, f.i. the hash of the previous block.

The pow solution is something like

```
Hash(nonce, msg.sender, challengenumber) < threshold
```

The miner varies the nonce until the condition is true.

At that point he found the solution and propose it for rewarding

If it is the first valid solution, it is rewarded, the block is declared mined and pass to blockchain. A new challenge number can be then calculated and the cycle start again

This is a general description. Hoping to help.